# Viewing projects using `org-ql`

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-ql

I use `org-ql` to view projects.

```
(defun my/view-projects ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'org-ql)
  (org-ql-search
    (org-agenda-files)
    '(and (tags "project")
          (not (todo "DONE"))
          (not (todo "XXXX")))
    :sort nil))
```

However, the outcome forgets the tree structure. For example, the following

```
* a    :project:
** b
*** c
```

got represented as

```
a
b
c
```

Wishing the outcome to preserve the tree structures more, I added `:super-groups '((:auto-parent))` in the form of `org-ql-search`. However, it doesn't make it better.

**Question** How to customize `org-ql` in order to view projects with the tree structures preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a `t` argument to the :super-groups.

```
(defun my/view-projects ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'org-ql)
  (org-ql-search
    (org-agenda-files)
    '(and (tags "project")
          (not (todo "DONE"))
          (not (todo "XXXX")))
    :sort nil
    :super-groups '((:auto-parent t))))
```

This results in this for me. I also note that although this doesn't exactly preserve the tree structure, if you select an item, you an see the path to it in the minibuffer. E.G. with the point on the c item below, you can see that it the path is file/a/b to get to it.

[image]

Comment: Indeed! Thanks :)